# How to rotate image selected row and unrotate image unselected row

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiimage, tableview

I have problem liked this: [image]

I have some row, when i click row 0, it expanded and dropdown image rotate. when i click row 1, it expand row 1 and unexpand row 0, dropdown image in row 0 back to normal (down arrow), and dropdown image in row 1 rotate (up arrow).

Here is my code so far:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! PaymentMethodCell
    let clickedRow = indexPath.row
    if indexPath.row == selectedRow{
        print("yang muncul selectedRow = -1")
        if cell.isSelected {
            selectedRow = -1
            print("This cell is deselected :\(selectedRow)")
            cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) * 180.0)
        }else{
            selectedRow = indexPath.row
            cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) / 180.0)
        }
    }else{
        if cell.isSelected {
            selectedRow = indexPath.row
            print("This cell is selected :\(selectedRow)")
            cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) / 180.0)
        }else{
            selectedRow = -1
            cell.ivExpand.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (180.0 * CGFloat.pi) * 180.0)
        }
        cell.lblclickedsubcell.text="00"
        print("cell.lblclickedsubcell.text:\(String(describing: cell.lblclickedsubcell.text!))")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

but the result is after i expand row 0 and then click row 1, row 0 unexpand and row 1 expanded. But dropdown image in row 0 still not back to normal (down arrow). it still as up arrow.

Here is cellForRowAt :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PaymentMethodCell", for: indexPath) as! PaymentMethodCell
    cell.ivPaymentMeyhod.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    cell.ivPaymentMeyhod.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.left
    cell.ivPaymentMeyhod.clipsToBounds=false
    //cell.ivPaymentMeyhod.kf.setImage(with: url!)
    cell.ivPaymentMeyhod.image = UIImage(named: "\(PaymentImageArray[indexPath.item])")
    let clickedRow = indexPath.row
    cell.lblclickedRow.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    let ContractNumber = "\(contractnumber!)"
    if(CustomUserDefaults.shared.isGuest() || ContractNumber==""){
        cell.lblContractNumber.text = ""
        cell.lblContractAmount.text = ""
    }else{
        cell.lblContractNumber.text = "\(contractnumber!)"
        cell.lblContractAmount.text = "\(contractamount!)"
    }
    if(clickedRow==0){
        cell.tableView.isHidden=true
        cell.XibView.isHidden=false
        let AlfaIndoView = HowToPayView.AlfaIndoNib()
        let cellwidth = cell.XibView.bounds.width
        print("cellwidth:\(cellwidth)")
        cell.XibView.addSubview(AlfaIndoView)
        AlfaIndoView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        AlfaIndoView.frame.size.width = cellwidth
    }else if(clickedRow==1){
        cell.tableView.isHidden=true
        cell.XibView.isHidden=false
        let POSindonesiaView = HowToPayView.POSindonesiaNib()
        let cellwidth = cell.XibView.bounds.width
        print("cellwidth:\(cellwidth)")
        cell.XibView.addSubview(POSindonesiaView)
        POSindonesiaView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        POSindonesiaView.frame.size.width = cellwidth
    }else if(clickedRow==2){
        cell.tableView.isHidden=false
        cell.XibView.isHidden=true
        cell.setUpTable()
    }else if(clickedRow==3){
        cell.tableView.isHidden=false
        cell.XibView.isHidden=true
        cell.setUpTable()
    }else if(clickedRow==4){
        cell.tableView.isHidden=false
        cell.XibView.isHidden=true
        cell.setUpTable()
    }else if(clickedRow==5){
        cell.tableView.isHidden=false
        cell.XibView.isHidden=true
        cell.setUpTable()
    }else if(clickedRow==6){
        cell.tableView.isHidden=true
        cell.XibView.isHidden=false
        let ATMbersamaView = HowToPayView.ATMbersamaNib()
        let cellwidth = cell.XibView.bounds.width
        print("cellwidth:\(cellwidth)")
        cell.XibView.addSubview(ATMbersamaView)
        ATMbersamaView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        ATMbersamaView.frame.size.width = cellwidth
    }
    return cell
}
```

Help me, please to repair this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be clearer if we could see your `cellForRow` code. As far as I can see, you are calling `reloadData()` at the end, so your cells are getting re-rendered, so you have to handle the arrow's orientations in your `cellForRow` code. So in pseudocode form, it would be a bit like the following:

*In `didSelect` function:*

```
selectedIndexPath = indexPath
//...other related statements
```

*In `cellForRow` function:*

```
if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
    //rotate arrow down
    //other relevant code
}
else {
    //rotate arrow up
    //other relevant code
}
```